# why do the bars change their location if i hide the icon or appname in the actionbar

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I used Eclipse to create a new Project and set the navigation type of my main activity to tabs and swipe. Everything works, but when I add these to hide the Icon and Title of the App

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

the two bars swap location. See screenshots below.

[image: before]
[image: after]

Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks you for helping me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was some behavior that if I remember right was introduced in ICS to support a specific design case we ended up not using. The idea was that in the absence of a home/up affordance or title, the tabs declare the title of the current content and guide the structure of the window even more than usual. This includes the actions/action overflow, so they show up beneath the tabs in the structural hierarchy of the window.

I would recommend avoiding this case; consider using a [split action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar) if you're using the actionbar tabs as the primary anchoring element for your window instead of home/up and/or a title. See the AOSP People and dialer apps as examples.